# How to convert multiple perl programs into a ready to install software?

Tags: perl, fasta

I have multiple perl programs written myself, which calculate genomic parameters, change headers, extract specific sequences from genome data or fasta sequences. Is there any way to build a package/ software which will calculate above things on clicking buttons in a menu and using my perl programs to do so.

Comment: Yes. There are plenty of ways. But you maybe need to separate the GUI part from the package part. This are two separate questions. Maybe it would be a good idea to search for those questions separately. This question is to complex to give a simple answer. And if you have no idea about GUI programming I suggest you search for some tutorials. There are many solutions. And all of this staff also depends on your targeted operating system too... which you have not mentioned.

Comment: I am on windows. Targeting windows.

Answer (score 4):

[PAR::Packer](https://metacpan.org/module/pp) is an utility which bundles an entire Perl project into a distributable executable with no external dependencies. It does so packing the Perl interpreter itself plus used modules (with XS binaries) into a single file. When user executes such a file, everything is unpacked to a temporary location, executed, and cleaned up on finish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to touch the GUI part of this because I don't think you're asking a question about that. It feels like you're asking a question about distribution. Please clarify if I'm wrong about this.

In my opinion, you should distribute your program as a zipped directory full of scripts, something like this:

```
geneprogram/
    geneprogram.pl
        resources/
            script1.pl
            script2.pl
            script3.pl
        output/
            script1.pl/
            script2.pl/
            script3.pl/
```

Etc. Let geneprogram.pl be your main GUI application. It can call your scripts as needed in separate processes and check their output, which should be in some understood place, such as the output/ directory I showed.

If your scripts have CPAN dependencies, I would try to "fat pack" them onto the script with [App::FatPacker](http://metacpan.org/pod/App%3a%3aFatPacker). Most biologists either don't use Perl at all (so don't know how to resolve their own dependencies) or even worse, *do* use Perl, and don't want to modify their installation to use your code. This won't work if your dependencies use C - aka Perl XS. For those libraries you will have to independently build the XS files for various architectures and release different architecture dependent versions of your software.

Finally, you need to consider whether your audience already has a suitable version of Perl installed on their system. If not, you should offer a "standalone" version of your distribution which has a fully executable perl in it.